# How to display java bean objects in a container without using get() in a loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, javabeans

I'm new to java. can you guide me on the below snippet. I have added 5 EmpBean objects to the ArrayList arr.

```
 List arr=new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        EmpBean eb=new EmpBean();
        eb.setFirstID(i);
        eb.setLastID(i);
        arr.add(eb);
    }
```

How do I display those 5 EmpBean objects in a single shot and not by using arr.get(0) and display individual EmpBean objects?

please help,

Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by single shot ?

Comment: and what do you mean by display? Do you want to print them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over your `ArrayList` in order to print its value:

**Example**

```
for (EmpBean bean: arr) {   
    System.out.println(bean.toString());
}
```

To override `toString` method in your class, you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("First id : %s, Second Id : %s", getFirstID(), getSecondID());//suppose you have a getter's for these variables.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your list with a `for` loop.

```
for (EmpBean empBean : arr)
{
    //do stuff with your empBean instance
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
    EmpBean empBean = arr.get(i);
    // do stuff with you empBean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display all object in single shot just print the arr object

```
System.out.println(arr)
```

Because List already override toString() method to display all it's elements in angular brackets [elements.]

To display each element use `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a primitive type `List` then you can get all the elements when you print the list itself, but incase of `List<Object>` you won't able to display the contents like that.
    In that case you have to use either a loop or an iterator:

1.

```
List<EmpBean>list = new ArrayList<EmpBean>();   
for (EmpBean ob:list) {   
    //do stuff with o   
}
```

2 .

```
List<EmpBean>list = new ArrayList<EmpBean>();   //you need to populate this list
Iterator iter = list.iterator();   

while (iter.hasNext()) {   
    Object o = iter.next();   
    //do stuff with o   
}
```

Comment: `Iterator` [can take a generic type too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), so you can declare it as `Iterator<EmpBean> iter` and then inside your loop use `EmpBean ob = iter.next()`

Answer (score 0):

come on guys for loop is soo java7, let's be up-to-date  :D

```
    arr.stream().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
```

- redefine toString in EmpBean to whatever you want to display :)

Comment: True, but it depends on whether or not @user3492471 is using JDK8. That information is not provided in the question.